# Is there a way to add a personal icon on Select ( Mantine)- not an image from Tabler Icons

Tags: javascript, next.js, mantine

I am new on Mantine and I`m trying to do a Search Component. In stead of using an image from tabler icons as is present in the mantine examples, I want to add a picture from my assets.

This is what I`ve tried

```
import { ReactComponent as SearchIcon } from '../../assets/search.svg';
import { IconHash } from '@tabler/icons';


<Select
    className={classes.searchBar}
    radius="xl"
    placeholder="Cauta produse, servicii, sau parteneri"
    itemComponent={SelectItem}
    data={data}
    searchable
    icon={<SearchIcon />}
    maxDropdownHeight={400}
    nothingFound="Nobody here"
    filter={(value, item) =>
        item.label.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase().trim()) ||
        item.description.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase().trim())
    }
/>
```

looks like if I import Icon Hash, the type is a function

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. `icon` is of type `ReactNode` and thus accepts every react node you pass to it. You should make sure that your svg is a react component, though.

The return type from `@tabler\icons` is indeed a function (actually, a component) because they're meant to be used as react components. You can check an example here and configure your svg accordingly: https://github.com/tabler/tabler-icons/blob/master/icons/123.svg?short_path=ce3b8f5.

Comment: The link in the answer no longer works.